# Why does my bread have a dip in the center?

Tags: bread

I made some white bread this evening and was quite happy with it except for the dip in the center:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I suspect maybe I left it to prove too long?  it seems like the air holes are too big and it has now lost it's structure.

Recipe was for 1kg flour I halved it:

```
500 g flour
12.5 g oil
20 g sugar
4 g dry yeast
10 g salt
300 g water

1) Mix all dry ingredients.
2) Add water and mix till incorporated. 
3) Add oil and mix
4) Knead for 5-6 min
5) Leave for 1.5 hours
6) Place in bread tin
7) Leave for 1-1.5 hours
8) Bake at 220 C for 30 min
```

It was a very wet dough. I may have got the liquid measurement wrong. I ended up working it as much as I could and it remained pretty wet the whole time.

Can anyone indicate what I did wrong to cause the dip?

Apart from the dip I am quite happy with this attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Your dough overproofed, or
2. the oven wasn't hot enough. In this scenario, the dough rises and then collapses before it can set

I would guess it was overproofed. Your recipe seems fine, though with all bread recipes, steps like "Leave for 1-1.5 hours" are highly variable depending on ambient heat in the kitchen, humidity, et cetera, and you should [really employ the finger poke test](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22927/how-can-you-tell-whether-bread-dough-is-ready-for-baking) to be certain.

**References**

- http://www.kingarthurflour.com/tips/bread-troubleshooting.html
- http://baking911.com/learn/baked-goods/bread/problems-and-solutions/general